# Prometheus - Request Rate not matching the Request Count

Tags: prometheus, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, promql

I am using prometheus to collect the request count/rate from Springboot Actuator Endpoint.

I sent **20 HTTP calls** to **myApp**

and **within 5 minutes**:

I executed this prometheus query to find total calls:

```
sum(http_server_requests_seconds_count{app='myApp'}) by (app,uri,status,method)
```

I get the expected result:

```
{app="myApp", method="GET", status="200", uri="/orders/summary"} 20   //Exact count 20!
```

However, When I do a rate query:

```
sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{app='myApp'}[30m]) * 60) by (app,uri,status,method)
```

I get:

```
`{app="myApp", method="GET", status="200", uri="/orders/summary"} 0.24059835115864528`
```

This above result does not match the real count - 0.24 * 30 = 7.2 = ~7-8 requests overall in the last 30 minutes, but I've done 20.

Why does this happen?